# CreateWindowW() fails a first time and then works afterwards [C++]

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi

So I'm trying to program an application that will help me log something and facilitate my actions in the future.

I wanted to make it as simple as possible, so I decided to use Win32API.

So I've made the necessary and created the windows/styles I needed, etcetera.

But there is something that triggers me a lot:

When I click on a button called "Add attendee," a window shall popup and asks me an attendee's name.

But when I click it a first time, nothing happens. But when I click it a second time, aforementioned window appears naturally.

So as to discover which problem it is, I decided to put the `GetLastError()` function, but it unfortunately returned 0 whenever I click on the "Add attendee" button a first time(when the window doesn't popup).

To know whether `CreateWindowW()` is the problem or not, I put `std::clog << "Test" << std::endl;` at the beginning of the `WM_CREATE` event. And as expected, the text doesn't show up a first time of clicking but it does a second time.

To know further, I decided to do the following:

- Put `std::clog << "Test1" << std::endl;` before `CreateWindowW()`;
- Put `std::clog << "Test2" << std::endl;` after `CreateWindowW()`;
- Put `std::clog << "Test3" << std::endl;` at the beginning of the `WM_CREATE` event;
- Put `std::clog << GetLastError() << std::endl;` after `std::clog << "Test2" << std::endl;`.

***Gotten results:***

> A first time:

- "Test1" is successfully written;
- "Test2" is successfully written;
- "Test3" fails and doesn't show up;
- `GetLastError()` returns 0.

> A second time:

- "Test1" is successfully written;
- "Test2" is successfully written;
- "Test3" is successfully written;
- `GetLastError()` returns 0.

After this, I then tried the following:

- Put `std::clog << "Terminate" << std::endl;` at the beginning of the `WM_DESTROY` and `WM_CLOSE` events.

And as expected, "Terminate" is not written when I click on the "Add attendee" button a first time, and it does show up a second time when I close the window.

So according to the obtained results, I then deduced that the problem comes from `CreateWindowW()`. But the real question is why? `GetLastError()` returns 0, so normally everything shall be fine.

Here are the parts of my code that imply aforesaid results(entire code), have fun:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <memory>

// Check if a log already exists

HWND hIncrease;
HWND hDecrease;

std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> GeneralDatabase;
BOOL LogExisting = false;

BOOL IfRegistered = false;


std::string TemporaryName;


BOOL IsWindowOpen = false;

BOOL IsAttendeeRegistered = false;

#define Size_X 900
#define Size_Y 600

// Values


HWND hAddAttBut;

int MaxScoreVal = 0;
std::string CoHostVal;
std::string TypeVal;
std::string LocationVal;

#define AttendeeButton 235

#define NewLOG 1
#define SaveLOG 2

#define AddAttendee 3
#define RemoveAttendee 4
#define DismissAttendee 5

HWND hPoint;
HWND hNames;

#define ListAttId 6
#define ListScrId 7
#define IncreaseButton (4<<3)
#define DecreaseButton (4<<4)

#define OtherButtonClick 18

#define DoneButton 22

HWND GeneralWindowHandler;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

// Attendees + scores windows
HWND hListAtt, hListScore;

// Format + new log 

HWND hAddEdit;
HWND NewLog;
HWND MaxScore;
HWND Type;
HWND CoHost;
HWND Location;
HWND hOtherText;

HWND hOther;
HWND hDone;
// Your screen resolution

unsigned short int xScreen, yScreen;

// Class of primary and second window

void FirstWindowInitiation(HWND);
void SecondWindowInitiation(HWND);
inline VOID IncreaseButtonAction(HWND hwnd);
void AddListString(std::string);

HWND hRank;

WNDCLASSW wc;

inline void Menus(HWND);
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hIn, HINSTANCE, LPSTR nShow, int nCmd){
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));
    wc.hInstance = hIn;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,0));
    wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    if(!RegisterClassW(&wc)){
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Failed to register the window.", L"Application error.", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return -1;
    }
    RECT rc;
    GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &rc);
    xScreen = rc.right;
    yScreen = rc.bottom;
    CreateWindowW(L"WindowClass", L"Training application.", WS_VISIBLE | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX, ((rc.right/2)-(Size_X/2)), ((rc.bottom/2)-(Size_Y/2)), Size_X, Size_Y, 0, 0,0,0);
    MSG msg_Translate;
    while(GetMessage(&msg_Translate, 0, 0, 0)){
        TranslateMessage(&msg_Translate);
        DispatchMessage(&msg_Translate);
    }
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp){
    GeneralWindowHandler = hwnd;
    switch(message){
        case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:{
            HDC dc = (HDC)wp;
            SetBkColor(dc, RGB(0, 0, 0));
            SetTextColor(dc, RGB(255, 255, 255));
            return reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0)));
            
        }
        case WM_COMMAND:{
            switch(wp){
                case NewLOG:{
                  if(IsWindowOpen){
                        MessageBoxW(hwnd, L"Cannot perform such an action; another window is already open.", L"", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
                        break;
                  }
                  int ResponseMessage = IDYES;
                  ((LogExisting == false) ? :ResponseMessage = MessageBoxW(hwnd, L"Are you sure you want to reset the log?", L"", MB_YESNO | MB_ICONINFORMATION));
                  if(ResponseMessage == IDYES){
                    LogExisting = true;
                    // Reinitiation
                    
                    if(hListAtt != NULL || hListScore != NULL){

                        SendMessageW(hListAtt, LB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);
                        SendMessageW(hListScore, LB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);
                        
                        memset(&hListAtt, 0, sizeof(hListAtt));
                        memset(&hListScore, 0, sizeof(hListScore));
                    }
                    
                    hListAtt = CreateWindowW(L"ListBox", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER, 150, 87, 300, 400, hwnd, (HMENU)ListAttId, 0, 0);
                    hListScore = CreateWindowW(L"ListBox", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER, 450, 87, 300, 400, hwnd, (HMENU)ListScrId, 0 ,0);
                    FirstWindowInitiation(hwnd);
                    memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));
                    
                    HINSTANCE hInst;
                    
                    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
                    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
                    wc.hInstance = hInst;
                    wc.lpszClassName = L"LogClass";
                    wc.lpfnWndProc = [](HWND hwnd2, UINT msg2, WPARAM wpp, LPARAM lpp)->LRESULT CALLBACK{
                        switch(msg2){
                            case WM_COMMAND:{
                                switch(wpp){
                                 case DoneButton:{
                                     char cohost[256], location[256], max[4], type[128];
                                     GetWindowText(CoHost, cohost, sizeof(cohost));
                                     ComboBox_GetText(Type, type, sizeof(type));
                                     ComboBox_GetText(MaxScore, max, sizeof(max));
                                     ComboBox_GetText(Location, location, sizeof(location));
                                     if(strcmp(location, "") == 0 || strcmp(max, "") == 0 || strcmp(type, "") == 0){
                                          MessageBoxW(hwnd2, L"One of the fields is empty, please fill it/them", L"", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
                                          break;
                                     }
                                     
                                     MaxScoreVal = atoi(max);
                                     if(strcmp(cohost, "") == 0){
                                         CoHostVal = "N/A";
                                     }
                                     else{
                                       CoHostVal = cohost;
                                     }
                                     LocationVal = location;
                                     TypeVal = type;
                                     
                                     DestroyWindow(hwnd2);
                                     ZeroMemory(&hwnd2, sizeof(HWND));
                                     break;
                                 }
                                 case OtherButtonClick:{
                                      if(SendMessageW(hOther, BM_GETCHECK, 0, 0) == 1){
                                          EnableWindow(hOtherText, true);
                                          EnableWindow(Location, false);
                                      }
                                      else{
                                        EnableWindow(hOtherText, false);
                                        EnableWindow(Location, true);
                                      }
                                      break;
                                 }
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                            case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:{
                                HDC dc = (HDC)wpp;
                                SetBkColor(dc, RGB(255, 255, 255));
                                return reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,255)));
                            }
                            case WM_CREATE:{
                                IsWindowOpen = true;
                                HFONT hFont = CreateFont(20, 0, 0, 0, FF_DONTCARE, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,0 , 0 , 0, "Arial");
                                SendMessageW(CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"Max score : ", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 40, 15, 100, 35, hwnd2, 0, 0, 0), WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, (LPARAM)TRUE);
                                MaxScore = CreateWindowW(L"COMBOBOX", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST ,180,15, 60, 210, hwnd2, 0, 0,0);
                                
                                for(int x = 10; x < 21; x++){
                                    std::stringstream ss;
                                    ss << x;
                                    std::string Result = ss.str();
                                    std::wstring w_Result(Result.begin(), Result.end());
                                    SendMessageW(MaxScore, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)w_Result.c_str());
                                }
                                
                                SecondWindowInitiation(hwnd2);

                                break;
                            }
                            case WM_CLOSE:{
                                char cohost[256], location[256], max[4], type[128];
                                GetWindowText(CoHost, cohost, sizeof(cohost));
                                ComboBox_GetText(Type, type, sizeof(type));
                                ComboBox_GetText(MaxScore, max, sizeof(max));
                                ComboBox_GetText(Location, location, sizeof(location));
                                if(strcmp(location, "") == 0 || strcmp(max, "") == 0 || strcmp(type, "") == 0){
                                    MessageBoxW(hwnd2, L"One of the fields is empty, please fill it/them", L"", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
                                    return 0;
                                }
                                MaxScoreVal = atoi(max);
                                if(strcmp(cohost, "") == 0){
                                         CoHostVal = "N/A";
                                }
                                else{
                                       CoHostVal = cohost;
                                }
                                LocationVal = location;
                                TypeVal = type; 
                                DestroyWindow(hwnd2);
                                memset(&hwnd2, 0, sizeof(hwnd2));
                                break;
                            }
                            case WM_DESTROY:{
                                DestroyWindow(hwnd2);
                                memset(&hwnd2, 0, sizeof(hwnd2));
                                IsWindowOpen = false;
                                break;
                            }
                            default:{
                                DefWindowProcW(hwnd2, msg2, wpp, lpp);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    if(!IfRegistered){
                      if(!RegisterClassW(&wc)){
                        MessageBoxW(hwnd, L"Failed to register class... Exiting.", L"", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
                        break;
                      }
                    }
                    
                    IfRegistered = true;
                    
                    CreateWindowW(L"LogClass", L"Format and log initiation", WS_VISIBLE | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX, ((xScreen/2)-300), ((yScreen/2)-200), 600, 400, 0, 0, 0, 0); 
                    
                  }
                  break;
                }
                case IncreaseButton:{
                    if(IsWindowOpen){
                        MessageBoxW(hwnd, L"Cannot perform such an action; another window is already open.", L"", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
                        break;
                    }
                    IncreaseButtonAction(hwnd);
                    break;

                }
                case AddAttendee:{
                    if(!LogExisting){
                        MessageBoxW(hwnd, L"No existing log  currently.", L"Error 404 - No log found", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                        break;
                    }
                    if(IsWindowOpen){
                        MessageBoxW(hwnd, L"Cannot perform such an action; another window is already open.", L"", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
                        break;
                    }
                    memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));
                    HINSTANCE hin;
                    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255,255));
                    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
                    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
                    wc.hInstance = hin;
                    wc.lpszClassName = L"HAddAttendee";
                    wc.lpfnWndProc = [](HWND hwnd3, UINT msg3, WPARAM wp3, LPARAM lp3)->LRESULT CALLBACK{
                          switch(msg3){
                              case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:{
                                  HDC dc = GetDC(reinterpret_cast<HWND>(wp3));
                                  SetBkColor(dc, RGB(255, 255, 255));
                                  return reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255)));
                              }
                              case WM_COMMAND:{
                                  switch(wp3){
                                      case AttendeeButton:{
                                          std::allocator<char> Alloc;
                                          char name[512], Rank[256];
                                          GetWindowText(hAddEdit, name, sizeof(name));
                                          GetWindowText(hRank, Rank, sizeof(Rank));
                                          if(strcmp(name, "") == 0 || strcmp(Rank, "") == 0){
                                              MessageBoxW(hwnd3, L"One of the fields is empty, please fill it.", L"", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                                              break;
                                          }
                                          if(GeneralDatabase.find(name) != GeneralDatabase.end()){
                                              DestroyWindow(hwnd3);
                                              MessageBoxW(GeneralWindowHandler, L"Name is already existing.", L"", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                                              memset(&hwnd3, 0, sizeof(hwnd3));
                                              break;
                                          }
                                          GeneralDatabase[std::string(name)] = std::vector<std::string>{std::string(Rank), "0"};
                                          IsWindowOpen = false;
                                          std::string Name;
                                          Name.append(std::string(name));
                                          TemporaryName = Name;
                                          Name.append(std::string("("));
                                          Name.append(std::string(Rank));
                                          Name.append(std::string(")"));
                                          std::wstring NameW(Name.begin(), Name.end());
                                          SendMessageW(hListAtt, LB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)NameW.c_str());
                                          char* score = Alloc.allocate(2);
                                          itoa(MaxScoreVal, score, 10);
                                          std::string Sentence = "0/" + std::string(score);
                                          std::wstring SentenceW(Sentence.begin(), Sentence.end());
                                          SendMessageW(hListScore, LB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)SentenceW.c_str());
                                          DestroyWindow(hwnd3);
                                          memset(&hwnd3, 0, sizeof(hwnd3));
                                         
                                          Alloc.deallocate(score, 2);
                                          break;
                                      }
                                  }
                                  break;
                              }
                              case WM_CLOSE:{
                                          char name[512], Rank[256];
                                          GetWindowText(hAddEdit, name, sizeof(name));
                                          GetWindowText(hRank, Rank, sizeof(Rank));
                                          if(strcmp(name, "") == 0 || strcmp(Rank, "") == 0){
                                              MessageBoxW(hwnd3, L"One of the fields is empty, please fill it.", L"", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                                              break;
                                          }
                                          if(GeneralDatabase.find(name) != GeneralDatabase.end()){
                                              DestroyWindow(hwnd3);
                                              MessageBoxW(GeneralWindowHandler, L"Name is already existing.", L"", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                                              memset(&hwnd3, 0, sizeof(hwnd3));
                                              break;
                                          }
                                          
                                          GeneralDatabase[std::string(name)] = std::vector<std::string>{std::string(Rank), "0"};
                                          IsWindowOpen = false;
                                          std::string Name;
                                          Name.append(std::string(name));
                                          TemporaryName = Name;
                                          Name.append(std::string("("));
                                          Name.append(std::string(Rank));
                                          Name.append(std::string(")"));
                                          std::wstring NameW(Name.begin(), Name.end());
                                          SendMessageW(hListAtt, LB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)NameW.c_str());
                                          std::allocator<char> Alloc;
                                          char* score = Alloc.allocate(2);
                                          itoa(MaxScoreVal, score, 10);
                                          std::string Sentence = "0/" + std::string(score);
                                          std::wstring SentenceW(Sentence.begin(), Sentence.end());
                                          SendMessageW(hListScore, LB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)SentenceW.c_str());
                                          DestroyWindow(hwnd3);
                                          memset(&hwnd3, 0, sizeof(hwnd3));
                                          
                                          Alloc.deallocate(score, 2);
                                          break;
                              }
                              case WM_CREATE:{
                                  IsWindowOpen = true;
                                  
                                  SendMessageW(CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"Name : ", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 5, 25, 55, 20, hwnd3, 0, 0, 0), WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)CreateFontW(20, 0, 0, 0, FF_DONTCARE, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0, L"Georgia"), (LPARAM)TRUE);
                                  
                                  hAddEdit = CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_BORDER, 75, 27, 215, 20, hwnd3, 0, 0, 0);
                                  
                                  hAddAttBut = CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Insert", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER, 110, 170, 80, 40,  hwnd3, (HMENU)AttendeeButton, 0, 0);
                                  
                                  SendMessageW(CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"Rank : ", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 5, 75, 55, 20, hwnd3, 0 ,0 ,0), WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)CreateFontW(20, 0, 0, 0, FF_DONTCARE, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0, L"Georgia"), (LPARAM)TRUE);
                                  hRank = CreateWindowW(L"ComboBox", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST, 75, 77, 215, 120, hwnd3, 0, 0, 0);
                                  if(strcmp(TypeVal.c_str(), "Joint departmental training") == 0){
                                      SendMessageW(hRank, CB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)L"SD");
                                      SendMessageW(hRank, CB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)L"MTF");
                                  }
                                  else if(strcmp(TypeVal.c_str(), "Cadet test") == 0){
                                      SendMessageW(hRank, CB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)L"Cadet");
                                      SendMessageW(hRank, CB_SETCURSEL, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)0);
                                      EnableWindow(hRank, false);
                                  }
                                  else{
                                      SendMessageW(hRank, CB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)L"Cadet");
                                      SendMessageW(hRank, CB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)L"Junior");
                                      SendMessageW(hRank, CB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)L"Sentinel");
                                  }
                                  break;
                              }
                              case WM_DESTROY:{
                                  if(!TemporaryName.empty()){

                                      AddListString(TemporaryName);
                                      TemporaryName = "";
                                  }
                                  DestroyWindow(hwnd3);
                                  memset(&hwnd3, 0, sizeof(hwnd3));
                                  IsWindowOpen = false;
                                  
                                  break;
                              }
                              default:{
                                  DefWindowProcW(hwnd3, msg3, wp3, lp3);
                                 
                              }
                          }
                      };
                    if(IsAttendeeRegistered == false){
                       IsAttendeeRegistered = true;
                       if(!RegisterClassW(&wc)){
                          MessageBoxW(hwnd, L"Failed to register.", L"", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                          break;
                       }
                    }
                    CreateWindowW(L"HAddAttendee", L"Insert attendee to the list", WS_VISIBLE | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX, ((xScreen/2)-150), ((yScreen/2)-125), 300, 250, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    break;
                }
                case DismissAttendee:{
                    if(IsWindowOpen){
                        MessageBoxW(hwnd, L"Cannot perform such an action; another window is already open.", L"", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
                        break;
                    }
                    if(!LogExisting){
                        MessageBoxW(hwnd, L"No log existing currently.", L"Error 404 - No log found", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case RemoveAttendee:{
                    if(IsWindowOpen){
                        MessageBoxW(hwnd, L"Cannot perform such an action; another window is already open.", L"", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
                        break;
                    }
                    if(!LogExisting){
                        MessageBoxW(hwnd, L"No log existing currently.", L"Error 404 - No log found", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case SaveLOG:{
                    if(IsWindowOpen){
                        MessageBoxW(hwnd, L"Cannot perform such an action; another window is already open.", L"", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
                        break;
                    }
                    if(!LogExisting){
                        MessageBoxW(hwnd, L"No log existing currently.", L"Error 404 - No log found", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case WM_CREATE:{
            Menus(hwnd);
            break;
        }
        case WM_DESTROY:{
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }
        default:{
            DefWindowProcW(hwnd, message, wp, lp);
        }
    }
}

void SecondWindowInitiation(HWND hwnd){
    
                                HFONT hFont = CreateFont(20, 0, 0, 0, FF_DONTCARE, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,0 , 0 , 0, "Arial");
                                HWND hType = CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"Type  : ", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 40, 70, 100, 35, hwnd, 0, 0, 0);
                                SendMessageW(hType, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, (LPARAM)0);
                                Type = CreateWindowW(L"COMBOBOX", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST ,180,70, 200, 210, hwnd, 0, 0,0);
                                

                                SendMessageW(Type, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)L"Cadet test");
                                SendMessageW(Type, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)L"Standard training");
                                SendMessageW(Type, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)L"Combative training");
                                SendMessageW(Type, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)L"Introductory seminar");
                                SendMessageW(Type, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)L"Joint departmental training");
                                HWND hCoHost = CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"Co-host(N/A)  : ", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 40, 125, 100, 35, hwnd, 0, 0, 0);
                                SendMessageW(hCoHost, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, (LPARAM)0);
                            
                                CoHost = CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_BORDER, 180, 125, 150, 20, hwnd, 0, 0, 0);

                                HWND hLocation = CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"Location  : ", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 40, 180, 100, 35, hwnd, 0, 0, 0);
                                SendMessageW(hLocation, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, (LPARAM)0);
                                Location = CreateWindowW(L"COMBOBOX", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST ,180,180, 160, 210, hwnd, 0, 0,0);

                                SendMessageW(Location, CB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)L"Zone-A(Surface exit)");
                                SendMessageW(Location, CB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)L"SD spawn");
                                SendMessageW(Location, CB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)L"Containment zones");
                                SendMessageW(Location, CB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)L"Outside the facility");
      
                                hOther = CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_AUTOCHECKBOX, 360, 176, 30, 30, hwnd, (HMENU)OtherButtonClick, 0, 0); 
 
                                HFONT hFontO = CreateFont(10, 0, 0, 0, FF_DONTCARE, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,0 , 0 , 0, "Arial");
                                HWND sOther = CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"Other", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 348, 200, 50, 30, hwnd, 0, 0, 0);   

                                SendMessageW(sOther, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)hFontO);

                                hDone = CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Save", WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 250, 300, 100, 50, hwnd, (HMENU)DoneButton, 0, 0);
                                
                                HFONT hFontB = CreateFont(20, 0, 0, 0, FF_DONTCARE, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,0 , 0 , 0, "Comic Sans MS");
                                SendMessageW(hDone, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFontB, (LPARAM)0);
}

void FirstWindowInitiation(HWND hwnd){
                    
                    SendMessageW(CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"Name: ", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 150, 25, 80, 40, hwnd, 0, 0, 0), WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)CreateFontW(30, 0, 0, 0, FF_DONTCARE, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, L"Bold"), (LPARAM)TRUE);
                    hNames = CreateWindowW(L"ComboBox", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST, 250, 29, 200, 500, hwnd, 0, 0, 0);
                    hPoint = CreateWindowW(L"ComboBox", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST, 460, 29, 65, 300, hwnd, 0, 0, 0);
                    
                    for(double x = 0.25; x != 4.25; x += 0.25){

                        std::stringstream ss;
                        ss << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10) << x;
                        std::string Num = ss.str();
                        std::wstring wNum(Num.begin(), Num.end());
                        SendMessageW(hPoint, CB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)wNum.c_str());
                    }   
                    HFONT Font =  CreateFontW(20, 0, 0, 0, FF_DONTCARE, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, L"Britannic Bold");                 
                    hIncrease = CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Increase", WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD, 550, 14, 150, 55, hwnd, (HMENU)IncreaseButton, 0, 0);
                    hDecrease = CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Decrease", WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD, 720, 14, 150, 55, hwnd, (HMENU)DecreaseButton, 0, 0);
                    SendMessageW(hIncrease, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)Font, (LPARAM)TRUE);
                    SendMessageW(hDecrease, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)Font, (LPARAM)TRUE);
                                        
}

void Menus(HWND hwnd){
            // Menus
            HMENU hMenu = CreateMenu();
            HMENU hFileMenu = CreateMenu();
            HMENU Attendee = CreateMenu();
            
            // Log menu
            AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_POPUP, reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(hFileMenu), L"Log");
            AppendMenuW(hFileMenu, MF_STRING, static_cast<UINT_PTR>(NewLOG), L"New log");
            AppendMenuW(hFileMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, 0);
            AppendMenuW(hFileMenu, MF_STRING, static_cast<UINT_PTR>(SaveLOG), L"Save log");
            
            // Attendee Menu
            
            AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_POPUP, reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(Attendee), L"Attendees");
            AppendMenuW(Attendee, MF_STRING, static_cast<UINT_PTR>(AddAttendee), L"Add an attendee");
            AppendMenuW(Attendee, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, 0);
            AppendMenuW(Attendee, MF_STRING, static_cast<UINT_PTR>(DismissAttendee), L"Dismiss an attendee");
            AppendMenuW(Attendee, MF_STRING, static_cast<UINT_PTR>(RemoveAttendee), L"Remove an attendee");
            
            SetMenu(hwnd, hMenu);
            
            // Lists
            
}
void AddListString(std::string str){
    std::wstring d(str.begin(), str.end());
    SendMessageW(hNames, CB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)true, (LPARAM)d.c_str());

}

inline void IncreaseButtonAction(HWND hwnd){
    char Name[256], point[4];
}
```

Comment: @Ron Sure! Will do so in a bit.

Comment: *I wanted to make it as simple as possible, so I decided to use Win32API* -- What? 
 The Windows API is one of the hardest API's to use.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Make sure it's *complete* and **minimal**.

Comment: @IInspectable I am working on it, please be patient.

Comment: @IInspectable I'll instead post the entire code, which should help you more than if I code a small part of it.

Comment: I understand that producing a [mcve] is an effort. If you want to improve your chances of getting help I suggest that you invest into that. It's certainly a *lot* easier for us to help, if we don't have to wade through piles of unrelated code.

Comment: @IInspectable I cannot do such, as I don't know which part of the code triggers the problem...

Comment: *I don't know which part of the code triggers the problem.* -- Well, that reinforces the claim that Win32 API is not "simple".  That's why a lot of frameworks exist that makes native programming in Windows much easier.

Comment: The link provides helpful instructions on how to construct a [mcve]. They do not require that you know beforehand, where or what the issue is.

Comment: @IInspectable Doing so requires much free time. And currently I am unable to completely rewrite my code as my free time is very limited.

Comment: you're calling CreateWindowW but then using calls like GetWindowText etc. without the "W" and passing non-wide chars. Either use wide characters or don't. If you do you do not actually need to specially call the "W" version of API calls. Just need to define the macro and use TCHARs everywhere.

Comment: @jwezorek I will attempt to use wide-char everywhere and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: @jwezorek But well replacing all "char" by "wide-char" would imply to completely change the conversions, the functions, the given values, etcetera. So it'd be the same thing as if I  completely start from scratch and write my code again, or even worse. And once again I don't have enough free time to do such.

Comment: Moreover if the problem was coming from there, CreateWindowW() wouldn't be affected as it has no relations with previous conversions.

Comment: look there are a lot of problems with this code. I am just saying you are mixing ansi and unicode all over the place. fix that first. also using std::allocator is odd. Just use std::to_string to convert an integer to an std::string.

Comment: @jwezorek Std::to_string is available in C++14 only, while my current compiler can only be set at the C++11 version only. Furthermore, I used `std::allocator` because it's more safe than casual pointers. 

The confusion of ANSI and Unicode all across the code will be fixed once I have enough free time.

Comment: `HINSTANCE hin; wc.hInstance = hin;` Your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of using an uninitialized variable. You are putting random garbage into your `WNDCLASSW`. My guess would be, it's `RegisterClassW` that fails.

Comment: The window procedure you set up for that class also exhibits undefined behavior, by way of reaching the closing brace without encountering a `return` statement. In particular, it does that when receiving `WM_CREATE`. The effect is returning whatever happens to be in EAX register, which is likely non-zero, which is a signal for `CreateWindow` to abort the creation of the window and return NULL.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik What's the solution then?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik And if `RegisterClassW()` fails, why does `GetLastError()` say nothing then?

Comment: The solution is to not use uninitialized variables, and to make sure that non-`void` functions actually return some value on all code paths.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Okay so first: there isn't any non-void functions that doesn't actually return a value designated for it. Second: using uninitialized variable or putting nothing don't differ. So even if I don't put any `HINSTANCE` to the `WNDCLASS` or `WNDCLASSW` class, it'd result the same thing as if I put an uninitialized `HINSTANCE`. So please review your methods. 

And so that you don't start complaining about what I said, I avoided the usage of uninitialized `HINSTANCE` and the problem still rises up.

Comment: The lambda that you assign to `wc.lpfnWndProc` in response to `AddAttendee` command contains exactly one `return` statement, in `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` handler. For all other messages, the control falls through to the closing brace without encountering a `return`. However, for many messages the return value is significant - among those `WM_NCCREATE` and `WM_CREATE`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The `WM_CREATE` event isn't even triggered; how would the problem come from a return value if the function isn't even called?

Comment: Likely because `WM_NCCREATE` handler already instructs `CreateWindow` to fail, by returning random garbage.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You're surprisingly right... I never thought that one day a return value in a future switch-case statement would fail a function... 

Now it works. Thank you for your time and especially your help.

Comment: Next time around, don't ignore your compiler's [warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4715). They are indeed helpful, like [this one](https://godbolt.org/z/qpc_Rk). Straight to the point. You would have had your issue solved within minutes.

Comment: @IInspectable You're right. Next time I will pay more attention to my compiler's warnings.

Comment: Hi， if your question has been solved, please post an answer and mark it to end this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is on behalf of @Igor Tandetnik:

All I have to do is to put `return 0;` at the end of every switch-case statement and every message as follows:

```
WM_CREATE:{
 ... // Code
 return 0; // If everything goes fine.
}
```